# How to enable S Mode in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, iso-image, windows-10s

***(I before also asked many questions about S Mode, but I want the latest Windows 10 Pro to be in S Mode as I couldn't update Windows 10 S).***

I followed [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-10-s-enable-s-mode?view=windows-10) article on enabling S Mode for ISO to clean install. But when I install the new ISO, S Mode isn't enabled.

Here is what I did:

- Downloaded Windows 10 Using media creation tool.
- Extracted ISO.
- Exported Windows 10 Pro from install.esd into install.wim
- Backed up Install.esd and replaced with the new exported install.wim
- Created unattend file using Windows SIM.
- Mounted install.wim
- Copied Unattend to `WIM_MOUNT_DIRECTORY\Windows\Panther` (Panther folder wasn't there so I created it.)
- Applied Unattend.
- Unmounted WIM.
- Created New ISO with  New files.
- Downloaded and installed VMWare
- Installed the new ISO

Then I saw that S mode isn't applied. After install, It should say `Windows 10 Pro in S Mode` (as I know) but it simply says `Windows 10 Pro` and also lets me to install Non-Microsoft Apps. What wrong did I did? Please suggest me a better way... I really want Windows 10 Pro to be in S mode....

***(I before also asked many questions about S Mode, but I want the latest Windows 10 Pro to be in S Mode as I couldn't update Windows 10 S).***

Comment: That's a clean install. Your question is posed in a way that it suggests you're asking how to re-enabled S mode on an existing install, where you left S mode.

Comment: Check https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-10-s-deployment-sxs?view=windows-11 under the "deployment" sections. It appears that you need to boot to WinPE (rather than the standard Windows Installer) and then use a script to apply your image instead. It is supposed to be done by system builders, there's no real friendly way for an end user to do it.

Comment: @Mokubai > Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try with that method.